# Custom cursor in html MetroApp

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs, internet-explorer-10

Well this is a 3 in one question.

I'm trying to build a game for windows 8 using html5 + winjs  [for apptivate](http://apptivate.ms/apps/1221/twisted-potions) but i'm  stuck with the cursor.

From what i know IE10 is not compatible with other formats than CUR/ANI. Does WinJS provide anything else to use a png as ani?

If i have to use CUR/ANI, does any of both have an alpha channel?

And finally can someone recommend me a tool to transform png to cur/ani?

Answer (score 0):

use default in cursor property -

```
  cursor:url(focus.ani),default;
```

this'll set cursor of any type cur/ani  & with cross browser support.

Comment: Does this work when you have an image with a .gif format? as I already tried this and it didn't work